# How to use mail() in php with gmail

Tags: php, email

Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\mailoutput\index.php on line 8
There was an error sending the email.

I am getting this message when I run the php code. I have this in a folder, I am doing a tut on php from thenewboston. Here is where my file is located C:\xampp\htdocs\series\mailoutput\index.php

here is the code in which I am running.

```
<?php
$to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'This is an email';
$body = 'This is a test email\n\nHope you got it.';
$headers = 'From: someone@gmail.com';


if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers))
  {
    echo 'Email has been sent. '.$to;
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'There was an error sending the email.';
  }
 ?>
```

My php.ini file has these settings

```
SMTP = ssl://stmp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 465
sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

In my sendmail.ini file these are the settings

```
smtp_server=ssl://stmp.gmail.com
smtp_port=465
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=(mypassword)
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
```

Not sure why this wont work or if there is an easier way to make this work.

Comment: don't use mail(). use phpmailer or swiftmailer

Comment: *"Don't be a card, be a munchkin"* - @Dagon

Comment: are these free to use?? I am just doing this for a class that I am taking and do not need to be spending more money on college than I have to lol.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you've misspelled the hostname here:

```
smtp_server=ssl://stmp.gmail.com
                  ^^^^
```

The hostname is **smtp**.gmail.com, not **stmp**.gmail.com.

That being said, don't use GMail to send mail from your web application. GMail isn't intended for this type of use - you can only send about 500 messages from a GMail account every day, and any spam complaints related to bulk email from such an account will be dealt with *very* harshly.

If you want to send email from a server that does not have its own mail server, use a dedicated mail delivery service such as Amazon SES, Sendgrid, Mailgun, *etc*.

Comment: Are these free and if they aren't are there any free ones out there?

Comment: Amazon SES has a free tier for EC2 users. It's also very inexpensive in low quantities (like, $0.10 per thousand messages sent).

Comment: THank you ! this was helpful